# Streaming and filtering a String to get a char[] array

Tags: java

I am trying to use something like below in order to stream and filter a given String by alphanumeric characters.

```
    List<String> alphanumeric = Arrays.asList("012345689abcdefhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split(""));

    char[] ssplit =  Arrays.asList(s.toLowerCase().split(""))
            .stream()
            .filter(alphanumeric::contains)
            .map(i -> i.charAt(0))
            .toArray(new char[0]);
```

But then I get the error below:

```
error: method toArray in interface Stream<T> cannot be applied to given types;
            .toArray(new char[0]);
            ^
  required: IntFunction<A[]>
  found: char[]
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) A
```

What am I doing wrong here? The error message makes zero sense to me

Comment: You can't do `.toArray(new char[0]);`?

Comment: That's what I am confused about

Comment: You have a Stream<java.lang.Character>. Its [toArray() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-) thus expects an IntFunction<java.lang.Character[]>, i.e. a function that takes an int as argument, and which creates an array of java.lang.Character. Instead, you're passing a char[]. What you need to pass is `Character[]::new`. But that will allow you to create a Character[], not a char[].

Comment: Indeed, I don't think that would work with `char[]`; changing the return type to `Character[]` and `toArray` to `.toArray(Character[]::new)` would be almost the same.

Comment: That makes sense and works, seems I got my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case regex might be the right solution, or changing your array to the type of `Character[]`. but however if you need a char array you could do something like:

```
char[] ssplit =  Arrays.asList(s.toLowerCase().split(""))
        .stream()
        .filter(alphanumeric::contains)
        .collect(Collectors.joining())
        .toCharArray();
```

Comment: It's simpler to write `s.chars()` to get a stream of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you would use streams for that.

Try the following instead:

```
String notLowerAlphaNum = "[^a-z0-9]";

char[] ssplit = s.toLowerCase().replaceAll(notLowerAlphaNum, "").toCharArray();
```